# Having a companion object seems to maask implicit calls to apply?

Tags: scala

Consider this code, which works:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
Some("bar").map(Foo)
```

It's technically calling Foo.apply, and that's implied.

But now if I have a companion object:

```
case class Foo(s: String)
object Foo {
    def apply(): Foo = Foo("default")
}
Some("bar").map(Foo)
```

Now this doesn't work because it is thinking of Foo.type, as in the object Foo.  You have to explicitly say .map(Foo.apply)

Is this justScalaThings, or am I doing something wrong?

(Yes I know in this trivial example I could just default the parameter in the case class declaration, this is just an example. Lots of reasons you might declare a companion object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, there is only `Foo.apply` fitting `.map(Foo)`.

In the second example you have declared an object called `Foo`, superceding `Foo.apply`, which you then try to pass into the `map`. Because `map` expects a parameter of type `String => A` compilation fails.

So as far as I am concerned you have to use `.map(Foo.apply)`.

This for example won't compile either:

```
case class Foo()

def map[A](f: Unit => A) = ???

map(Foo)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/0YS83ON/0)

Comment: Thanks.  After messing with it, that was also my conclusion, that since it's now ambiguous whether you mean Foo.apply or Foo.type, you have to just specify.  Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not `Foo.type`, it's `Foo`. You are attempting to pass the `object Foo`. You can't pass a type as a parameter (types are compile time only), those are two different things. Anyways, I am happy I could help.